# How to add dummy cycles to a NOR Flash on STM32

Tags: stm32, bare-metal

My question is related to the QSPI interface on an STM32F7.

An example on how to interact with different NOR Flashes via QSPI programmatically on an STM32 board can be found here: https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/stm32-external-loader/tree/contrib/QSPI_Drivers

So my question is, how to configure the dummy cycles?
I am a bit confused because there is a member called "DummyCycles" in the QSPI_CommandTypeDef interface:

Normally an interaction via QSPI on a STM32 looks like:
QSPI_CommandTypeDef sCommand;

```
if (QSPI_WriteEnable() != HAL_OK) 
{
    return HAL_ERROR;
}


/* Some command --------------------------------- */
sCommand.Instruction = 0x9E; //READ_ID
...
sCommand.DummyCycles = 0;  // dummy cycles defined via the STM32 interface

if (HAL_QSPI_Command(&hqspi, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK) 
{
    return HAL_ERROR;
}
```

These are the dummy cycles defined via the STM32 interface.
On the other hand in every NOR Flash data sheet like:
https://www.gigadevice.com/flash-memory/gd25b512me-2/

the dummy cycles are defined via:

[image]
[image]

How to set the dummy cycles for an NOR FLASH like the gd25b512me?
Or is it enough to just do (for command 0x9E)

```
sCommand.DummyCycles = 8;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the gd25b512me it is enough to do

```
sCommand.DummyCycles = 6;
```

Because the default number of dummy cycles for the gd25b512me are 6.

And the STM32 interface has to be in sync with the used NOR Flashes configuration.